# uuid changes everytime in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

Here are some steps by following I'm getting different UUID eachtime.

1. Install app
2. get UUID
3. Ask permission for location and push notification (cause I need it in login page)
4. allowing both permission
5. get UUID
   (Here I'm getting different UUID which I got in step 2)
6. Login to firebase via facebook
7. Logout firebase and facebook
8. get UUID
   (Here I'm getting different UUID which I got in step 2 and 5)
9. Again  login to firebase via facebook
10. Again logout
11. get UUID
    (Here I'm getting different UUID which I got in step 2, 5 and 8)

Here is my code for getting UUID.

```
let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString.lowercased()
```

Why I'm getting different UUID each time?

Comment: because that is what UUIDs are there for. *If* you get the same UUID twice you seriously broke something.

Comment: Are you trying to get a device id?

Comment: It seems like you are mistaking _UUID_ for _UDID_. _UUID_ is just a random identifier, so every time that piece of code is run you're supposed to get a new ID. _UDID_ on the other hand is the unique identifier of the device and hence that's constant.

Comment: You are calling `NSUUID.init()` with `NSUUID()`. From the doc: `Initializes a new UUID with RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes.` RANDOM. You are misunderstanding the purpose here.

Comment: So I need to store somewhere and use that each time I need?

Comment: You can have a unique token with help of apple API - func generateToken(completionHandler completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void). This will uniquely identify the device.